# Spring 4 Properties annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am trying to use spring 4 too load properties and use them in the classes, but it I can't get it to work. This is not an MVC appication and the reported duplicatet does not give me any clue on my issue.  Here is what I got in my test project:

The main class:

```
 public class Main {

    public static void main(String...args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfig.class);
        Tester t = new Tester();
        t.testBean();
    }
}
```

ApplicationConfig Class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"nl.foo.propertiestest"})
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class ApplicationConfig {
//Spring framework will know what to do with this class

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

The Tester Ckass:

```
public class Tester {
    @Autowired
    Environment env;

     @Bean
     public void testBean() {
         System.out.println("testBean start");
         String a = env.getProperty("test");
         System.out.println("property = " + a);
         System.out.println("testBean e");
     }

}
```

The application.properties:

```
test=hello tester
```

The application gives a null pointer exception on `tring a = env.getProperty("test");` but it seems to load the properties, as it gives an error when the properties file is not in the class path.

How do I get the property retrieved?

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC, it has to do with the fact that you created your `Tester` using **new**, so spring doesn't know how to autowire it.  This is *exactly* the issue in the linked duplicate.

Comment: When I change the `Tester t = new Tester();` to `Tester t = (Tester) context.getBean(Tester.class);` it still does not work, I get `No qualifying bean of type [nl.foo.propertystest.Tester] is defined`

Comment: Without seeing how your tester bean is defined in your application context, I can't speak to why you can't load your bean.  That is, however, a different problem than this one, so you should probably post it as its own question if you can't figure it out.

Comment: After some more hours I found the solution, in Main class, change 

`Tester t = new Tester();` 
to 
`Tester t = context.getBean(Tester.class);`. 

In the ApplicationConfig  class, add: 
`@Bean
    public Tester tester() {
     return new Tester();
    }` 

and in the Tester class, remove the `@Bean`.
And it all works!